# Naming conventions down to the Instance Variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model `ProductFeature`

a controller called `product_feature_controller.rb`

I am writing the 'edit' method of my CRUD for this controller. In the edit method, I created an instance variable named `@productFeature` and set it equal to `ProductFeature.find(:id)` and I send this instance variable to my view to be used by a `form_for(:product_feature)`. I have found that my form will not populate its fields with the current data from the record I am pulling up.  After pulling hairs for some hours, it dawned on me that my error was all in the way named my instance variable.

It should be named @product_feature instead of @productFeature. This seems like a trivial detail, but I'd really like to know why this is the case. How does this even work? I mean how does Rails know to populate my form based on the way the instance Variable is named?  I hope my question is clear, just seeking further edification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the symbol `:product_feature` (in the `form_for`) is going to look up an instance variable based on that symbol. It doesn't do any transformation, and will be looking for a `@product_feature` variable. As long as they match, you should be okay, but the Ruby world uses underscores between words.

Also, models should be named with a leading capital, `ProductFeature`, by convention. I don't know if this will cause any issues, but it's counter to the norm.

Comment: thank you sir, quite helpful. Now just to be clear, I have to write my symbol as ':product_feature' in order for my 'form_for' tag to locate the proper model to use right? I couldn't have just wrote my symbol as ':productFeature' and solved this issue without creating another?

Comment: And you are correct, the model name does lead with capitalization. I fixed it in my question, thanks.

Comment: @Guided33 Haven't tried it, but if the model variable is `@productFeature` and the symbol is `@product_feature`, I would expect it to work. Easy enough to try (and report back! :)

Comment: Yea, it seems to work fine.  I guess this means that the only time the actual Model is referenced is when I go to save the parameters from the form.  So I can name the symbol and my instance variables what ever i want, as long as they match each other Rails conventions are preserved.

Comment: @Guided33 Mmm, no; I think the form tag helpers use that instance variable to re-populate the form, like on a validation error, or for populating when editing. The Rails *convention* is to use underscores--but you're correct, as long as the match, you're okay :)